# Redirect between different protocols

Tags: java, web

In my Java project, I'm using the class `HttpUrlConnection` to read a web page.
The issue is that when I get a redirect from http to https, it doesn't work:
it downloads a blank page and I get an error `303`.

If I use this function on a normal redirect (http -> http) I get a correct result (e.g. code `200` on destination page).

Here is the code I use to open a page:

```
HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.toURL().openConnection();
yc.connect();
```

where url is a `URIobject`.

Answer (score 0):

LMGIFY:  [Java HttpURLConnection Follow Redirect Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/)